# Issue with images loading in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Facing an issue with images loading in Chrome browser whereas its working fine in Firefox.I am  trying to load and image at the header and the other two on two buttons. Using the below code for the same.

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 4em;
    background: url(https://mycrm.com/browser/images/CNT2528706.png) no-repeat top right;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: thin solid #dedede
}

a.button {
    display: block;
    min-height: 50px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #f99752 url(https://mycrm.com/browser/images/CNT2532535.png) no-repeat 5px center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px 0 60px;
    border-radius: 5px
}
```

Comment: It's not an issue with the image or chrome, I checked out the image (in chrome) copied & pasted the url, and it rerouted to the homepage of the site. I think that chrome is getting the bg image from the homepage, which isn't an image. firefox prevents automatic rerouting like that.

Comment: by the way, really nice site :)

Comment: Actually the url I gave is not the exact one. I gave the sample URL for security purpose and there is no issue with the image location.

Comment: Can you give the url of the image then? or at least put it somewhere where I can use it in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL6srr98/)

Comment: It is not acccessible outside the vpn or outside office network. The content is not get updated in JSFiddle, when I try to update FYI.

Comment: but you can get the image and put it on a image hosting site, can't you?

Comment: Please see, if you can access the following urls.
https://i.imgsafe.org/04b96d2.png

https://i.imgsafe.org/07429e2.png

Comment: @Tricks for the Web -  are you able to access those images?

Comment: Yes, here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2was9pj0/. I can't see anything wrong with the code, I'm in Chrome 49.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Code:

```
 header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 4em;
    background: url("https://mycrm.com/browser/images/CNT2528706.png") no-repeat top right;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: thin solid #dedede;
}

a.button {
    display: block;
    min-height: 50px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: url("https://mycrm.com/browser/images/CNT2532535.png") no-repeat 5px center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px 0 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Don't forget to end the with `;` else the code will not work, also use `""` Like: background: url("Example");

Comment: Charles - Not working even after adding the ; and "" as suggested.

Comment: user1611498 - I try to go to the link of the image and redirects to main page of the website, Try to save the image and use it in background: https://mycrm.com/browser/images/CNT2528706.png

Comment: Like: background: url("Directory of the image file");